# how can i fix this eror in laravel" 1005 Can't create table `englishcollage`.`role_user` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6

i want to make a ACl migration in my Laravel project ... (version 6)

but i receive  this annoying error :

General error: 1005 Can't create table `English Collage`.`role_user` (Errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

English Collage is my database .

```
 Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {

          $table->increments('id');
          $table->string('title_fa'); // edit posts
          $table->string('title_en'); //edit-posts
          $table->timestamps();
      });


    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title_fa'); // edit posts
        $table->string('title_en'); //edit-posts
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->Integer('role_id')->unsigned();

        $table->Integer('user_id')->unsigned();


            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

    });

    Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->unsignedInteger('permission_id');

        $table->unsignedInteger('role_id');


        $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

    });
```

and this is my users migration:

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('level')->nullable();
            $table->integer('age')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

this structure work in laravel 5 but  laravel 6 has issue with this

i tried big integer  and  unsigned big integer  even i tested primary_key for role_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create Foreign key the data type for the `child column` must match the `parent column` exactly.

Since `id` is a `bigIncrements` i.e. `unsigned big integer` in `users` table   then `role_user.user_id` must be `unsignedbigInteger`, not an `unsignedInteger`.

**Change** below in your `role_user` table

```
 $table->Integer('user_id')->unsigned();
```

**to**

```
 $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely this line

```
$table->Integer('role_id')->unsigned();
```

If the `id` field of the roles table is not an Integer (the latest Laravel uses unsignedBigInteger) then MySQL won't be happy.

Try

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
```

Comment: It does not matter whether it's `integer` or `bigInteger `

Answer (score 0):

Try this , i hope it work fine

```
Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {

      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('title_fa'); // edit posts
      $table->string('title_en'); //edit-posts
      $table->timestamps();
  });


Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title_fa'); // edit posts
    $table->string('title_en'); //edit-posts
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->Integer('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade')->unsigned();

    $table->Integer('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade')->unsigned();

});

Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->unsignedInteger('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

    $table->unsignedInteger('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');


});
```